# Can we differentiate between 'an object' and 'a region of space'?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, subatomic

Is it *strictly* accurate to say:

> All of what we know or can say about physical reality is inferred, deduced or derived from the observation of interactions of regions of space.

To qualify:

By *'space'* I mean:

- sub-atomic dimensions probed in particle accelerators

---

The 'question behind my question' in more straightforward words is:

> Is it ever possible for us to differentiate between the notion of *'a
>   region of space exhibiting certain observable properties and behaviours'* and *'an object contained in a region of space'*.

Comment: If we have a proton in some region of space we wouldn't say the region of space had a mass of a GeV and a charge of $+e$. We'd say there was a proton with a mass of a GeV and a charge of $+e$ somewhere in that space and we just didn't know exactly where it was.

Comment: Thanks John. My question is probing along the lines of _geometrodynamics_. What evidence do we have that we are looking at 'a proton contained in a region or volume of space' versus 'a region or volume of space that exhibits proton like properties and behaviour' ?

Comment: So you're asking if particles are some property of spacetime akin to [Wheeler's idea of geons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics))?

Comment: Exactly. Clifford. Wheeler. Einstein.

Comment: How would we know that was the case? No experiment has ever suggested it and no stable geon geometry has ever been found.

Comment: Not wanting to engage in a oppositional back-and-forth, so perhaps one last question: _How would we know that was_ **not** _the case?_ Is there any known experiment that can prove the distinction?

Comment: *Is there any known experiment that can prove the distinction?* - no. We would need to construct a theory based on your suggestion that could make quantitative predictions that differed from the predictions of our current theory (quantum field theory). Then we could design an experiment to test those predictions. In the absence of such a theory we don't know what we would need to test i.e. we don't know what experiment would be a suitable test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physics is about measurements and observations. Mathematical models with specific laws, postulates, principles distilled from experiments and observations, are constructed and tested against measurements, old and new predictions.  If the model is not falsified, it is validated and accepted until or if a measurement/observation falsifies it.

In addition, the models belong to specific frameworks, when a model is falsified, it usually is in a specific framework, and then a new framework is "invented" that will cover the new observation. Example Newtonian physics holds for low velocities, it is falsified by high velocities, and special relativity was "invented" for that framework, and has not as yet been falsified. Classical mechanics holds for large dimensions , if was falsified for atomic dimensions and quantum mechanics had to be invented to  model data and observations.

You ask:

> Is it ever possible for us to differentiate between the notion of 'a region of space exhibiting certain observable properties and behaviors' and 'an object contained in a region space'.

From the comments you are discussing the realm of General Relativity, where experiments are hard to come by, and one has to rely on cosmological observations. The properties of particles as distilled in the standard model of particle physics do not rely on the gravitational observations as the effects of gravity are not measurable in experiments. The gravitational coupling is very very much smaller than the other classified three forces.

Thus one would have to assign by fiat the properties of the particles to the region of space they happen to occupy, or develop a new theory.

Now string theories afaik are the only mathematically consistent theories where the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) can be embedded in the quantized states of the strings. But strings work in at least nine dimensions and maybe more.

If you extend your "geometrodynamics" to the high dimensional space of strings, and if a definitive string theory emerges that can make testable predictions for experiments, then the theory would completely describe all energies projected in our four dimensional world , and would just wait for validation or falsification. It would model from empty space to the elementary particle table. In this sense there would be no differentiation.

Comment: _if a definitive ... theory emerges that can make testable predictions for experiments, then the theory would completely describe all energies projected in our four dimensional world ... and ... would model from empty space to the elementary particle table._ **In this sense there would be no differentiation.** Perfectly clear. Thank you.